# How does Error_Message() work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How does `Error_Message()` function works and where is the raised error data stored?

I have to write some code to read all errors currently raised but not handled yet (`CATCH` block is not reached end, in our DB it takes some minutes for a `CATCH` block to finish). Now the question is:

Where can I get data related to raised errors?

Improve (UPDATE): suppose that I have a code like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
  DECLARE @a INT = 1 / 0
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
  -- What can I write instead of ERROR_MESSAGE() to get the same result?
END CATCH
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Why can't you use `error_message` there? Why do you need alternatives? From an external process you can use extended events or SQL trace to see error messages.

Answer (score 1):

it is depend on Error Severity Level that you get in Error

**Msg 547,** **`Level 16`**, **State 0, Line 11**

**The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_
Categories".**

1. As a general rule, errors with a severity level of 16 or higher are
   logged automatically to the SQL Server log and the Windows
   Application log.
2. Errors with a severity level from 19 through 25 can be specified
   only by members of the sysadmin fixed server role.
3. Errors with a severity level from 20 through 25 are considered fatal
   and cause the connection to be terminated and any open transactions
   to be rolled back.
4. Errors with severity level 0 through 10 are informational only.

asp er my First point you can get Error at SQL Sever Log and Window Application Log

**for SQL Server log**

**Object Explorer in the Management ➪ SQL Server Logs node lists the
logs. Double-clicking a log opens SQL Server’s cool Log File Viewer**

[image]

**For  Window Application Log**

**Control Panel ➪ System
and Security ➪ Administrative Tools ➪ Event Viewer.**

[image]

Comment: thanks for detailed really useful reply!
But I think there must be a simple way to get that data, aint?

Comment: Why does your screenshot show a severity 14 error? Presumably you used `raiserror ... With log`. How does that help the OP with normal errors not raised that way? Such as the divide by zero one shown in the question.

Comment: Normal Error means..?? @MartinSmith

Comment: Runtime error not raised with `raiserror` and severity 11 to 16 are the normal errors.